# nodejs restify error -- callback serving request treated as static function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, static-methods, restify

I am initiating a node js web server with restify module.

```
server = restify.createServer();
server.post('/getData', DataManager.getData);
```

Handler for `/getData` path looks like this:-

```
DataManager.prototype.getData = function(request, response, next) {
    var body = JSON.parse(request.body);
    var key = body.key;

    callback = function(err, instance) {
        if(!err && instance) {
            response.send(instance);
        }
        else {
            response.send('err');
        }
        return next();
    }

    MongooseModel.findOne(key, callback);
}
```

When I shoot 2 concurrent requests to `/getData` with different payloads, the server throws `[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]` error and doesn't respond to the second request.

I am looking for a remedy to this.

--

I think, restify treats `DataManager.getData` as a static function. Instead of serving each request to `/getData` with a new object of `DataManager` it is using single static instance of it. While the first request is still executing as per `nodejs`, the second request tries to send a response which is why nodejs says `can't set headers after they are sent`. I'm arriving at this conclusion as I tried shooting two sequential requests instead of parallel ones and my code works just fine in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a context problem with your callback!!!!

You should specify response & next for the session... Did you try to declare it with a `var`, it may solve your problem I think...

```
var callback=.....
```

In other case you need to pass both response() & next() to it...

Comment: Declaring callback with var helps. Could you please elaborate on why this works? What's the difference between a callback with and without var? I am a javascript beginner.

Comment: Without var your fonction is "global" and honestly I'm not sure about what is is "closure" (i think all call to callback take last function but not sure)

Comment: With var your create a local instance or your function for each getdata call, And your are sure about it's closure..... Hope it's more clear like this :)